# How Do I Detect Which Radio Button Is Being Pressed In Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, casting

I have write this code:

```
from tkinter import * 

count = 0

def Pick_Celeb(): 
    for v in range(len(Celeb_Photos)): 
      if (z.get() == v): 
          print("You ordered "+Celeb_Names[z])  

def click_button(): 
    global count 
    count += 1
    print("You have clicked the button "+str(count)+" Times")

def submit():
    Username = Enter_Box.get() 
    print("You have set your username to: "+Username)
    delete()
    Enter_Box.config(state=DISABLED)

def delete(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END)

def backspace(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(len(Enter_Box.get())-1,END)

def display():
    if (Check_Button_Status.get()==1): 
        print("You agree")
    else: 
        print("You don't agree")

def click(event):    
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END) 
     

Window = Tk() # Instaniates an instance of a window 

z = IntVar()

Elon_Musk_Photo = PhotoImage(file="Elon_Musk(50x28).png")
Jeff_Bezoz_Photo = PhotoImage(file="Jeff_Bezoz(50x28).png")
Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo = PhotoImage(file="Mark_Zuckerberg_Small(50x30).png")

Celeb_Photos = [Elon_Musk_Photo, Jeff_Bezoz_Photo, Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo]
Celeb_Names = ["Elon Musk", "Jeff Bezoz", "Mark Zuckerberg"]

for Index in range(len(Celeb_Names)):
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(Window,
                              text=Celeb_Names[Index], 
                              variable=z, 
                              value=Index,  
                              padx=25,
                              font=("Impact",20),
                              image=Celeb_Photos[Index],
                              compound="right",
                              width=250,
                              command=Pick_Celeb) 
    
    radiobutton.place(x=500, y=50+Index*45)

Photo = PhotoImage(file="Pig2.png") 

Like_Button = PhotoImage(file="Like-Button2.png")

Window.geometry("900x600") 

Window.title("The Ultimate GUI Program") 

Window.iconbitmap("AngryBird9.ico")

button = Button(Window,
                text="Click me",
                command=click_button,
                font=("Comic Sans,",10,"bold"),
                fg="Red",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="Red", 
                activebackground="black",
                image=Like_Button,
                compound="bottom")


button.place(x=50,y=50) 

Window.config(background="white")


Label = Label(Window,                                       
              text="You are using the best program ever!", 
              font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
              fg="red",
              bg="white",relief=RAISED,bd=10,
              padx=10,
              pady=10,image=Photo,
              compound="bottom")


Label.place(x=170,y=170)  

Enter_Box = Entry(Window,font=("Arial"),fg="Black",bg="Gray") 

Enter_Box.place(x=460,y=220)

Submit_button = Button(Window,        
                       text="Submit",
                       command=submit)

Submit_button.place(x=700,y=220)

Delete_button = Button(Window,       
                       text="Delete",
                       command=delete)

Delete_button.place(x=750,y=220)

BackSpace_button = Button(Window,   
                          text="Backspace",
                          command=backspace)

BackSpace_button.place(x=795,y=220)  

Check_Button_Status = IntVar()

Checkbox = Checkbutton(Window,         
                       text="I agree to the TOS",
                       variable=Check_Button_Status,
                       onvalue=1,
                       offvalue=0,
                       command=display)

Checkbox.place(x=200,y=100) 

Enter_Box.insert(0,"Enter username")
Enter_Box.bind("<Button-1>",click)

Window.mainloop()
```

To produce this GUI window:

[image]

However when trying to click a Radio button I get this error:

"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not IntVar"

What I can understand from this is that I need to somehow cast an IntVar value to a numerical value that can used as an indice for the list but I can not find anything anywhere that explains how to, so can I fix this or do I need to do this another way?

Comment: You don't need that `for` loop in `Pick_Celeb()`, `z.get()` directly gives you the index that you can use with your lists.

Answer (score 1):

i think that the issue is that you are trying to use "z" witch is an intVar directly as an index for the "Celeb_Names" list.
here is how you can modify your code :

```
def Pick_Celeb():      
 selected_index = z.get()     
 if selected_index < len(Celeb_Names):         
  print("You ordered " + Celeb_Names[selected_index])     
 else:         
  print("Invalid selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the method in your code, the radiobuttons will be created. But only the last radiobutton will have the variable name 'radiobutton'.

To avoid this, the radiobuttons can be created with Dynamic_variable method. But this method is strongly discouraged.

```
for Index in range(len(Celeb_Names)):
    Dynvar = f'radio_btn{index+1}'
    globals()[Dynvar] = Radiobutton(Window, text = Celeb_Names[Index])
    globals()[Dynvar].pack()
```

So it's better to name each radiobutton separately

```
#create a string variable
rad_var = = tk.StringVar()

radio_btn_1 = Radiobutton(Window, text="Elon Musk", variable=radvar, value= 'Elon Musk')
radio_btn_1.pack()

radio_btn_2 = Radiobutton(Window, text="Jeff Bezoz",  variable=radvar, value= 'Jeff Bezoz')
radio_btn_2.pack()

radio_btn_3 = Radiobutton(Window, text="Mark Zuckerberg",  variable=radvar, value= 'Mark Zuckerberg')
radio_btn_3.pack()
```

In the functions, use the condition as follows:

```
if rad_var.get() == "Elon Musk":
    #your code here
    
elif rad_var.get() == "Jeff Bezoz":
    #your code here
    
else:
    #Your code here
```